# MySQL Date and Interval - records between dates

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a syntax problem I can't sort out.  I'm just trying to grab all records from last 3 days.

```
$result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM records WHERE today BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE AND DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 3 DAY)");
```

today is DB column for the MySQL timestamp and looks like this: 2014-10-30 16:35:58

This query only gives results for 1 day, not 3.  Can someone help with the syntax problem?

Comment: `last 3 days` -- are you looking for `date_sub` instead? -- `BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 3 DAY) AND CURRENT_DATE`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 3 DAY)` means three days in the *future*, not three days ago. Unless the `today` column is supposed to represent (say) the date for which a future appointment is scheduled, you usually want to *subtract* days from a date. So get three days ago, you need to use `DATE_SUB`. I'd recommend this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM records
WHERE today >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 3 DAY)
```

Comment: That worked!  Thanks for the thorough explanation.  Many thanks.